# Linking to app store review page in branch.io

Tags: branch.io

Is there any way to create a link within Branch.io which instead of loading the installed app, would instead bring the user to the app's page in the store where the  user could review the app. This would be used in email marketing.

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

If you want users to be directed to a specific page you can make the links as Web Only.

1. For iOS: When you create the link specify the $ios_redirect to your App page on the App Store and add `$web_only: true` to your deep link data. The Branch link thus created will redirect to the web URL you have specified as the iOS redirect (in this case the App Store page).
2. For Android: When you create the link specify the $android_redirect to your App page on the Play Store and similarly add `$web_only: true` to your deep link data. The Branch link thus created will redirect to the web URL you have specified as the Android redirect (in this case the Play Store page).

PS: For Android, if you have App links setup for your App clicking on the link will redirect to your App irrespective. For this to work, you should remove the App links configuration in your App and the Branch dashboard if any.

You can check the list of possible parameters for configuring links [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/dashboard/xamarin/#keys-and-values).

Edit:
1. Add the $web_only parameter in the Deep Linking section
[image: link parameters]

2. Set the iOS and Android redirect to the App Store and Play Store URLs respectively.

[image: redirect URLs]

Comment: guess I didn't explain myself. I'm looking to create a web url (in the Dashboard) which when clicked on an iPhone will bring user to App Store (not website), and on Android will bring users to the Play Store (not web store)

Comment: @MonOve You can do the same thing for the URL you create on the Branch dashboard. I have updated my answer for more information.